# combining ec2 with linode

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-hosting

We are a small startup planning to launch a tomcat-mysql based s/w.

Hosting our primary server on ec2 is costly compared to linode. but we have 2 month/year of peak usage. for which we'll like to have a backup servers.

Is it possible to use linode as primary host and use ec2 occasionally. if so, what will be the best architecture.

Comment: voting to move to ServerFault, but let me tell you -- this sounds pretty insance (unless your data is really, really tiny)

Answer (score 0):

If your database is available externally to wherever it is hosted, and the latency isn't too bad, create two instances of your application and flip the DNS to whichever one you need to get the job done.

Given that this is Java, have you looked at using [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) which will run small Java applications for next to nothing?